# Android native methods called from Java side

Tags: android, native-code, android-audiorecord

How can I get reach to the native methods called from Java side in Android? My problem is specifically related to AudioRecord class in Android Media package. I read the source code of AudioRecord.java. I found out that most of the jobs is performed by native methods, such as:

native_setup(...), native_start(...), native_stop(...), native_read_in_byte_array(...), native_read_in_direct_buffer(...)

I downloaded Android source code but I could not reach these methods. And I don't actually know the way to reach them. I seek for these methods in libraries I found in source code directories, but I couldn't success. If anybody may have an idea, I would be appreciative to hear. Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

I think I found them. After using the Linux command

grep -r "native_read_in_direct_buffer" ./ANDROID_SOURCE/.*

I found the corresponding cpp files.

AudioRecord.cpp is located in: ~/ANDROID_SOURCE/frameworks/av/media/libmedia/ directory,

android_media_AudioRecord.cpp is located in ~/ANDROID_SOURCE/frameworks/base/core/jni directory.

I wanted to share it as a reference to other possible programmers willing to reach the same/similar source files.